# Как приклике на кнопку выводилось цифра в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Я хотел чтоб при клике на кнопку выводилась цифра на Entry и при нажатии на галочку цифры пропадали.
Вот полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint


root = Tk()
root.geometry('192x393+500+150')
root.title("Угадай число!")
root["bg"] = "black"

loadimage = PhotoImage(file="galca.png")

number  = randint(1, 100)
l1 = Label(text="Это число от 1 до 100",
           font="Arial 12",
           bg="black",
           fg="white")
l1.place(x=10, y=10, width=171, height=21)
l2 = Label(text="",
           font="Arial 12",
           bg="black",
           fg="white")
l2.place(x=10, y=40, width=171, height=21)

variant = Entry(root, bg="black",
                      fg="white",
                      font="Arial, 30",
                      justify="center")
variant.place(x=10, y=80, width=171, height=61)
b1 = Button(text="1")
b1["bg"] = "gray27"
b1["border"] = "0"
b1["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b1.place(x=10, y=270, width=51, height=51)
b2 = Button(text="2")
b2["bg"] = "gray27"
b2["border"] = "0"
b2["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b2.place(x=70, y=270, width=51, height=51)
b3 = Button(text="3")
b3["bg"] = "gray27"
b3["border"] = "0"
b3["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b3.place(x=130, y=270, width=51, height=51)
b4 = Button(text="4")
b4["bg"] = "gray27"
b4["border"] = "0"
b4["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b4.place(x=10, y=210, width=51, height=51)
b5 = Button(text="5")
b5["bg"] = "gray27"
b5["border"] = "0"
b5["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b5.place(x=70, y=210, width=51, height=51)
b6 = Button(text="6")
b6["bg"] = "gray27"
b6["border"] = "0"
b6["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b6.place(x=130, y=210, width=51, height=51)
b7 = Button(text="7")
b7["bg"] = "gray27"
b7["border"] = "0"
b7["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b7.place(x=10, y=150, width=51, height=51)
b8 = Button(text="8")
b8["bg"] = "gray27"
b8["border"] = "0"
b8["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b8.place(x=70, y=150, width=51, height=51)
b9 = Button(text="9")
b9["bg"] = "gray27"
b9["border"] = "0"
b9["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b9.place(x=130, y=150, width=51, height=51)
b0 = Button(text="0")
b0["bg"] = "gray27"
b0["border"] = "0"
b0["activebackground"] = "gray19"
b0.place(x=10, y=330, width=111, height=51)
bb = Button(image=loadimage)
bb["border"] = "0"
bb.place(x=130, y=330, width=51, height=51)




root.mainloop()
```

[image: Как сейчас выглядетЖ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации вашей идеи, вам нужно привязать функцию к каждой кнопке.

Пусть это будет `func(key)`, где `key` - аргумент, передаваемый при нажатии кнопки.
И функция `remove()`, вызываемая при нажатии на "галочку"

**Функция:**

```
def func(key):
    variant.insert(END, key)

def remove():
    variant.delete(0,END)
```

**Привязка кнопки:**

```
# при нажатии на кнопку "1", будет вводиться значение "1"
b1 = Button(text="1", command = lambda x='1': func(x)))

# при нажатии на галочку текст будет стираться
bb = Button(image=loadimage, command = remove)
```

---

*Если интересует, то могу предложить также реализацию проверки числа:*

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def timer(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    variant.delete(0,END)


def remove():
    if int(variant.get()) == number:
        variant.delete(0,END)
        variant.insert(END, 'Вы угадали!')
    else:
        variant.delete(0,END)
        variant.insert(END, 'Не угадали :(')

    # задержка в 2 секунды, перед тем, как надпись пропадет
    delay = 2
    Thread(target = lambda x = delay: timer(x)).start()
```

Comment: Задержку можно сделать без многопоточости через root.after

Comment: Спасибо огромное.